# Protocols for streaming A/V feeds

Tags: http, encoding, tcp, video-streaming, webcam

What protocols do web cameras use for streaming audio/video feeds over the internet? HTTP? TCP? How is each frame sent inside the protocol? For example, if they use HTTP, does the web cam software encode each frame and tack it on as a query string parameter like:

```
http://www.some-url.com?encoded-frame=WJDJ84FU84F85594DK3DK
```

or, is the encoded frame set as the HTTP request's body? Similar question for TCP or any other protocol that is used.

I'm asking because I'd like to stream a web cam to a web server and have software that receives each encoded frame, decodes it, and does something with it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the question in OP  is open ended because it's not like there is 'one fixed set of protocols(TCP/UDP)' used in this kind of applications and also its scope is large, due to various technologies involved in this end-to-end solution of Camera capturem encoding , streaming, decoding/processing. In the case you mentioned if it is going to be likely that the webcam and the Web server are going to be on same LAN, then well you can as well use TCP/IP and then server can process it. Because on LAN latencies won't be high, so TCP would serve good. Else if on WAN, then UDP/IP can be of help.
There are plenty of tutorials online to get basics of using TCP/IP  or UDP/IP sockets and its programming concepts. Then there are tutorials about streaming, packetization etc of Video data.

I don't see how HTTP can be of use here to send from webcam to a server.

For starters

http://streaminglearningcenter.com/streaming-video-consulting.html

Hope this is good to get you started.

Comment: Thanks @goldenmean. I'll give you the check for lending your advice, but wanted to update this question with what I decided upon. I'm going to write some homegrown software to capture the A/V feed from the camera, encode it to MJPEG, and then send each frame grab over the internet using UDP/IP. On the client-side a VLC player with be listening on the correct port and will convert the encoded MJPEG signals (collected off the inbound UDP packets) into a rendered video. I had hoped there would be an "out of the box" FOSS solution but this is the best I could find. Thanks again.